# Data Validation using a conditional (IF) formula

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, excel-formula

I am building a spreadsheet to assign employees to work on projects based on their individual skills sets.

I have three named lists that contain the names of employees that are certified to work on different projects.  I to use these lists as sources for dropdowns via Data Validation.

I am trying use the following formula in order to determine named listed appears in the dropdown:

```
=IF(SEARCH("ABC",A15),List_1,IF(SEARCH("DEF",A15),List_2,IF(SEARCH("GHI",A15),List_3_,List_4)))
```

However, Excel tells me that this formula evaluates to an error.  I cannot find out why.  Can someone point me to how to correct the formula?  Or if there is a better way to have the lists populate based Cell A15's value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the `SEARCH` with the `ISNUMBER` function. `SEARCH` raises an error `#VALUE!` if it doesn't find the substring. `ISNUMBER` returns `FALSE` if it's argument returns anything other than a number. Finally, `SEARCH` returns an index number of what position in the string the substring was found, if one is found. Combine this knowledge to write: `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ABC",A15)),List_1,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DEF",A15)),List_2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("GHI",A15)),List_3_,List_4)))`

Double check the parens I'm on my phone. GL.

Comment: Thank You my Friend.  Worked like a champ.